# Windows Phone ApplicationBar MenuItems space issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have developed an app for Windows Phone 7 (which is also being updated to Windows Phone 8) and I have a peculiar UI issue in Application Bar.

I'm adding 4 ApplicationBarMenuItems to the ApplicationBar.

But when the app renders the ApplicationBar, it shows extra space at the bottom of the appBar.

This doesn't happen when I used 3 ApplicationBarMenuItems.

Note: This behavior is observed in both WP7.5 & WP8.

I could not find any official documentation that explains this or a workaround. I came across the below post,

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/metro-design-guide-v1/

which states,

> *The application bar moves to a specific size depending on the number of menu items in it. If you have 4 items, it will show the size for 5
>   – so visually it may not look quite right. Try optimizing for 3 or 5
>   menu items if you can for the best, tightest look.*

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. "Try optimizing for 3 or 5 menu items if you can" is not the answer that i expected.

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround and you are right that there is no info in MSDN about it ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))